# D3.js Collapsible tree: Adding a label for each level

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working on a project which needs a label for each of the levels of the collapsible tree in D3.js(https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). I am facing tough time in adding the same. The label I require is added in the attached screenshot. The label should populate for each level as soon as click on each level and disappear as it the tree rolls back. Could anyone help me out with this.
 [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the update method to track the levels from the node items. Maintain a unique sorted hash of all the depth values from the node items used to plot the chart. Once you have the sorted depthHash array, plot the text on the top of your chart. Below is a fiddle i have modified for your reference. 
    http://jsfiddle.net/deepakpster/vomxqxov/3/

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

flare = "http://rawgit.com/mbostock/1093025/raw/a05a94858375bd0ae023f6950a2b13fac5127637/flare.json"
d3.json(flare, function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
    // Showing the labels for the level of depths.
    // Using underscore.js to do the pluck, uniq.
  var depthHash = _.uniq(_.pluck(nodes, "depth")).sort();
  svg.selectAll("g.levels-svg").remove();
  var levelSVG = svg.append("g").attr("class", "levels-svg");
    var levels =  levelSVG.selectAll("g.level");
  levels.data(depthHash)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "level")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d*180 + "," + 10 + ")"; })
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d){
      return "level-" + d; 
    });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  /*  
  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  */
  var ww = 30, hh = 20
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("height", 1e-6)
    .attr("width", 1e-6)
    .attr("x", -ww/2)
    .attr("y", -hh/2)
    .attr("rx", 3)
    .attr("ry", 3)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", ww)
    .attr("height", hh)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .attr("dx", -10)
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```